Fair use for US work outside of US in countries that don't have such law
If thre is a work created in US, like a Matrix Poster published on Wikipedia:

Can I use this work using "Fair use" in different countries that don't have such law?
In Poland, we have similar named law called "Dozwolony użytek", but it works differently. It allows using copyrighted work for your own use if you get it from publicly available sources (like download from the internet). And you can use protected works in education (but only in school classroom for educational purpose).
Maybe this is obvious, but I have no idea If I can for instance take this poster and put it into presentation. I would also like to know if I have a presentation that contain a poster from the Matrix, can I publish the whole work (presentation) under Creative Commons license?
Unfortunately, I don't know any copyright lawyer that I can ask this.

The law where you copy/publish the work applies
The Berne Convention, which both the USA and Poland are signatories to, requires each to afford their own copyright protection to works produced in another member country. So, this work, originally created under US law, has copyright protection under Polish law; and a lot of other countries’ law as well.
So, if you copy/publish this in Poland, you need to comply with Polish law.

So if you are a Polish citizen and copy a DVD while on holiday in the USA, it would be US copyright law, if you copy it at home in Poland it would be Polish copyright law.
